# Two forms reporting to different tabs in same spreadsheet. Script I am running triggers when either form is submitted. How do I limit to one?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two form response sheets collecting data in one spreadsheet.  My goal is to move data from "SA Concussion F/U" to "EHR Responses" and then delete the row from "SA Concussion F/U"

This should only be triggered on submit of form to "SA Concussion F/U"

The problem that the script is being triggered when either form receives a submission.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
`function copydata() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("SA Concussion F/U");
var LastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
ss.getSheetByName("EHR Responses")
.appendRow(sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn())
.getValues()[0])
sheet1.deleteRow(LastRow);`
```

Comment: You can tell which form has done a submission by looking at e.range which tells you which is the range of cells that were edited on the linked sheet one linked sheet is attached to one form and the other to another form.  The sheet name is `e.range.getSheet()`

Answer (score 1):

```
function twoFormSubmitsToOneSpreadsheet(e) {
  const obj={'linkedsheet1name':'form1','linkedsheet2name':'form2'};
  if(obj[e.range.getSheet().getName()]=='form1') {
    //do stuff for form 1
  }
  if(obj[e.range.getSheet().getName()]=='form2') {
    //do stuff for form 2
  }
}
```

[form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)